# Undefined reference when building Metakit

Tags: c++, linker

I'm trying to use the Metakit library latest update, but I always get an `Undefined reference` in this piece of code:

```
bool c4_FileStrategy::DataOpen(const char *fname_, int mode_) {
  d4_assert(!_file);

#if q4_WIN32 && !q4_BORC && !q4_WINCE
  int flags = _O_BINARY | _O_NOINHERIT | (mode_ > 0 ? _O_RDWR : _O_RDONLY);
  int fd =  - 1;

  if (GetPlatformId() != VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
    fd = _open(fname_, flags);
  if (fd ==  - 1) {
    WCHAR wName[MAX_PATH];
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, fname_,  - 1, wName, MAX_PATH);
    fd = _wopen(wName, flags);
  }
  if (fd !=  - 1)
    _cleanup = _file = _fdopen(fd, mode_ > 0 ? "r+b" : "rb");
#else 
  _cleanup = _file = fopen(fname_, mode_ > 0 ? "r+b" : "rb");
#if q4_UNIX
  if (_file != 0)
    fcntl(fileno(_file), F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
#endif //q4_UNIX
#endif //q4_WIN32 && !q4_BORC && !q4_WINCE
```

The strange thing (for me) is that, I get this linker error on this line:  `fcntl(fileno(_file), F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);` witch is used only for Linux. The #else part appears in gray, so I thought that code never compiles, so why do I get this undefined reference then ?

Any thoughts ?

PS: with my current older version I have no problem (2.4.6).

edit: I am on Windows and using Tornado (unfornatelly)

edit 2: this is how q4_UNIX is defiend:

```
#if defined (__MINGW32__)
#define d4_OS_H "win.h"
#elif defined (MSDOS) && defined (__GNUC__)
#define q4_DOS 1
#elif defined(unix) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__GNUC__) || \
defined(_AIX) || defined(__hpux)
#define q4_UNIX 1
#elif defined (__VMS)
#define q4_VMS 1
#elif defined (macintosh)
#define q4_MAC 1
#elif !defined (d4_OS_H)
#define d4_OS_H "win.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are on Windows. This means that this line:

```
fcntl(fileno(_file), F_SETFD, FD_CLOEXEC);
```

should never have been compiled. This means that the `#ifdef`'s are flawed.

You have three options for fixing:

1. Fix the defines so that this doesn't get compiled and gets preprocessed out instead.
2. Comment out the offending lines manually.
3. Try including `<fcntl.h>`, which *might* fix the issue. That is assuming you even have `<fcntl.h>`.

Comment: #3: that header is included for q4_UNIX and I also tried to included outside the #define. #2: I cannot comment them because I think I need for linux too (later) #1: how can I fix them ? The older version appears to be the same and I don't get any problem there...

Comment: @vBx: how is q4_UNIX defined?

Comment: In the old library it was like this: #define q4_UNIX 1 , in this new one, Visual Studio says that is not defined :-/

Comment: @vBx: if `q4_UNIX` is not defined then this line would have been preprocessed out. Are you __sure__ this is the problem and are you __sure__ that `q4_UNIX` is not defined?

Comment: Well if I go to his definition/declaration with Visual Studio, it says that, but I searched for it and I found it in the same place like the old version, I will post it to my question so you can see better how is defined.

Comment: @vBx: you can _try_ fixing it by changing that block to this: https://gist.github.com/2283696/97dcbc52056f69344c459ed4930cbc76edd03c58 No guarantees though.